# Cannot load shared 'project' in Windows Universal app after upgrading to Azure SDK 2.6

Tags: visual-studio, azure, win-universal-app

I've just installed the [April 2015 release of the Azure SDK](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/downloads/archive-net-downloads/). It is version 2.6 and previously I was on 2.5. Now one of my projects will not load. It is the shared project in a Windows Universal application.

When I right-click the project and choose 'reload' I get the pop-up error

> The method or operation is not implemented

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

The output window gives more detail:

> Things.Shared.shproj : error  : The composition produced a single
>   composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the
>   CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
>
> 1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
>     ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.References.IBuildDependencyProjectReferencesService
>     RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.References.IBuildDependencyProjectReferencesService
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Deployment.ProjectReferenceMaintenanceService.ProjectReferencesService
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.References.IBuildDependencyProjectReferencesService")'
>   on part
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Deployment.ProjectReferenceMaintenanceService'.
>   Element:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Deployment.ProjectReferenceMaintenanceService.ProjectReferencesService
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.References.IBuildDependencyProjectReferencesService")
>   -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Deployment.ProjectReferenceMaintenanceService
>
> Resulting in: Cannot get export
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Deployment.ProjectReferenceMaintenanceService.WireUp
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ConfiguredProject.AutoLoad")'
>   from part
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Deployment.ProjectReferenceMaintenanceService'.
>   Element:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Deployment.ProjectReferenceMaintenanceService.WireUp
>   (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ConfiguredProject.AutoLoad")
>   -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Deployment.ProjectReferenceMaintenanceService

The other parts to the Windows Universal app (the Windows 8.1 project and the Windows Phone 8.1 project) have two Azure NuGet packages installed: Windows Azure Mobile Services 1.3.2 and Windows Azure Storage 4.3.0. (N.B. Those two projects load without issue.)

This is not a show stopper for me since uninstalling the Azure SDK 2.6 removes the load failure. To uninstall I go via the Control Panel to 'uninstall or change a program' and then uninstall Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - v2.6

[image: uninstall]

I would like to know how to fix this without uninstalling the Azure SDK 4.6.

Comment: In the absence of an answer [I've cross-posted this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8123821-dcb1-477f-a746-f6f016a724ea/cannot-load-shared-project-in-windows-universal-app-after-upgrading-to-azure-sdk-26?forum=azuremobile) to the MSDN Azure Mobile Services forum too.

Comment: From that MSDN thread this problem seems to be also affecting some Xamarin projects, but there is a patch ready doe to be released soon. I'll post an answer when it is released.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Over on [the Azure Mobile Services forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8123821-dcb1-477f-a746-f6f016a724ea/cannot-load-shared-project-in-windows-universal-app-after-upgrading-to-azure-sdk-26?forum=azuremobile) Chuck Weininger has posted the following answer:

> The [fixed] build of Azure SDK 2.6 is now available, but it may not have
>   propagated to all download servers yet.
>
> You can run the Web Platform Installer and if you don’t have the new
>   build installed, it should allow you to install 2.6 again.  But it
>   might not if you are accessing a download server that doesn’t have the
>   new bits yet.  If WebPI doesn't allow you to install 2.6 again, then
>   wait a few hours and try again.
>
> The build number for the version with the fixes is build
>   2.6.30508.1601. You can identify the build of the SDK from Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2013 – v 2.6. The Version column will display the build
>   number

I have followed Chuck's instructions and have the new build and the shared project now loads without issue.

Comment: Even though the Platform Installer was used to install the SDK originally I could not see it available as an update. But I manually re-downloaded and installed from here and that fixed the problem: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46892.

Answer (score 2):

> We have been able to reproduce the issue, but don't have a workaround at this time.  If you want to use the Universal App projects with VS 2013, you will have to uninstall Azure SDK for VS 2.6.  The issue does not happen on VS 2015 RC if you would like to give that a try.  We hope to have news soon about how we can get a fix for this issue on VS 2013.
>
> Chuck Weininger, Dev Lead, Microsoft

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8123821-dcb1-477f-a746-f6f016a724ea/cannot-load-shared-project-in-windows-universal-app-after-upgrading-to-azure-sdk-26?forum=azuremobile&prof=required#de621720-3afc-458c-ba85-f691be9e74c1

Comment: I mention that in my comments on the question

Comment: I just encountered this as well. It's completely broken my solution, but I've already deployed Azure projects with the 2.6 tools and reverting them will not be fun =/